# Embed div elements in php foreach?

Tags: php, html

I tried to embed 2 elements with class "elementcontent" in element with class "row", can someone tell me what's wrong in my code (see second code block)?

This is raw code without if request to embed 2 elements in one:

```
  <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($items as $key=>$item) {
    ?>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="elementcontent">element content</div>
        </div>
    <?php

        $i++;

        }
    ?>
```

This is my code where i try to embed elements:

```
        <?php
            $i = 1;
            foreach ($items as $key=>$item) {
        ?>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="elementcontent">element content</div>
        <?php
              if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                  echo '</div><div class="row">';
              }
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php

            $i++;

        }
        ?>
```

This way i found with help from this source: [How can I alternate div elements in php foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242416/how-can-i-alternate-div-elements-in-php-foreach-loop)

Comment: What is the desired output and what seems to go wrong?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? Do you have 2 divs and you want to put the data in these 2 divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place two elements in each row you want to test the `$key` -

```
<?php
    $items = array('foo', 'bar', 'glorp', 'baz');

    foreach ($items as $key=>$item) {
        if($key % 2 == 0){
            echo '<div class="row">';
            echo '<div class="elementcontent">'. $item . '</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="elementcontent">'. $item . '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

By doing it with the key there is no need for an iterator.

Comment: *Yeah Sam*, that's the way to do it ;-)

Comment: *I was thinking of expanding the answer some Ralph.* Perhaps after I do the presentation today. So much to know about `mod` @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're a pretty "mod" guy there *Sam* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, what you want is a ROW element, with 2 ELEMENTCONTENT inside of it.

You can do this like this:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
$row = ($i % 2 == 0); ?>
    <?php if ($row): ?><div class="row"><?php endif; ?>
    <div class="elementcontent">element content</div>
    <?php if (!$row): ?></div><?php endif; ?>
<?php 
    $i++; 
}
if (count($items) % 2 === 1) {
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Every 2 items will be wrapped with a div with a class row.
I've used [PHP's alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for more elegant code.

Answer updated due to an error and also checking if the number of items is an odd number, to close the div tag.

Comment: Answer updated after @Jay Blanchard comment.